# PHP returning empty value,

Tags: php, function, logic

I've got a tree function that crawls up the branches of a tree to see where the branch of another tree sits.

When I call `findparents3` and a branch is found then I return the primary key of the node.  When I echo the node from the calling function I get null but the echo in the function is normal.

Poured over this and can't work out where I am wrong..:-(

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function findparents3($objparent){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblrepobjects where objid = ?  and reportid = ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$objparent, $_POST['reportid']]);
    $studies = $stmt->fetchALL();
            
    if (count($studies)>0){
        $t = $studies[0]['mapid'];
        return  $t;
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblobjects where objid = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$objparent]);
        $studies2 = $stmt->fetchALL();
        if ($studies2){
            $this->findparents3($studies2[0]['objparent']);
        }
        else{
            $t = "0";
                
            return  $t;
        }
    }
}

public function findobjtree($callname, $objval, &$objtree){
    //echo "<br>looking for:" . $callname;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblobjects where callname like \"%" . $callname . "%\"";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $studies = $stmt->fetchALL();
    if ($studies){
        $objtree[] = $studies[0];//add to object tree
        $s = $this->findparents3($studies[0]['objparent']);
        echo $s;
    }
}
```

Comment: `findobjtree` is insecure, parameterize everywhere.

Comment: To user's previous comment, see [this info](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like) example with `like`.

Comment: Within `findparents3()` do you mean to pass through another `return` the value from `$this->findparents2($studies2[0]['objparent']);`? the findparents2 method is called but findparents3() might be throwing away its return value

Comment: Within findparents3()  should be calling findparents3($studies2[0]['objparent']);  I redreafted for this and forgot to change number.

Comment: Why `fetchAll()` as a multidimensional structure when it looks like you are only expecting one row?  Do we get to see some sample table data? and sample submission data? to create a [mcve]?